# Git: How to bring a project branch with sub-branches easily into master?

Tags: git, merge, branch, pull-request

Situation: A repository with a master branch (green line) and a project branch, which has multiple sub-branches. Our rule is, everything that goes into Master, goes there via a pull request.

[image: Git Branches]

This situation should be quite common, - but somehow I did not find an answer to my question:

How can I bring that blue branch properly and easily back into the green master branch?

I have tried rebasing, and the first 20 commits go through well, but thereafter, it asks me to resolve conflicts manually for every following commit. I would prefer to have to solve the whole thing just *once*, not for every commit in the micro project. Can't I just rebase the "sum of commits" of the blue branch to the master branch?

One colleague suggested to create a new (pink, not in the diagram) branch, branched from the same green commit as the blue micro project branch, create a diff between the commit we branched from and the last blue commit - and apply that diff to the pink branch. This seems feasible to me, but I wonder if there is really no solution which is more git-style...?

Comment: *"Can't I just rebase the "sum of commits""* - so you want to squash all the commits on the branch?

Comment: Why not merge instead of rebasing?

Comment: our process on github is: 1) create pull request, 2) wait for code review, 3) merge into master (or release branch). Direct merge into master would lack code review. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

For several reasons, rebasing is probably not the best solution.  (I'll come back to why in case you're unconvinced.)

The thing typically done (because yes, this is a common situation) is simply merge the "blue" branch into master.  The "sub-branches" don't affect this, and this doesn't affect them, so it's just as simple as any other merge.  Since you mention PR's you must be using some sort of hosted repo (github?); but surely whatever service you're using, it supports just doing a plain old merge of a PR...

Now why is this better than trying to rebase?

First, your branch/merge style looks a lot like gitflow.  The commit topology is one of the benefits of gitflow, so why destroy it by rebasing?  At any rate, you have all this stuff on and from the blue branch, that isn't linear.  If you try to rebase it, by default it will try to make that all into a linear history.  You can stop that with `--preserve-merges`, but (1) it may mess up the merges anyway, and (2) it will still replace every commit with a new, untested commit (which may not compile or run properly because the changes may not apply cleanly to the new base).

Additionally, rebasing will only affect at most a singe ref.  Any tags, or other local branches, that might have pointed to the old history... still point to the old history, creating a hard-to-fix splinter in your history graph.  You can't fix it by just rebasing those other refs - they'd get further splintered due to commit timestamps.  You'd have to figure out where each one belongs (relatively speaking) in the "new" graph and move them.

Then there's the bigger issue: the remote branch refs.  They still point to the old history too, and moving them creates an "upstream rebase" condition that will break every existing clone (except yours).  It sounds like you want this to be a step in your release process; do you really want to make everyone go through a recovery process after every release?

Rebasing has its uses, but this really isn't one of them.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds quite good. Do you think it is a good practice to ...
1. create a new branch (black) from master
2. merge blue branch into black branch
3. create pull request from black branch to master

This would maintain our pull-request approval process...

Comment: Ok, but why not just create the PR from blue to master?  I may be missing something, but if a direct PR won't work then I don't see why going through an extra branch is going to help anything

Comment: Hm, no, does not work either. You are right. It looked as if it would work when I created the PR in github ("Able to merge. These branches can be automatically merged.", but once that PR is created, it says "This branch cannot be rebased due to conflicts".

Comment: So again, it sounds like you're assuming a PR has to be rebased; generally there's no reason that should be the case.  Again I don't know what software you're using, so I could be missing something, but you *should* be able to merge a PR instead of rebasing it